# Django manage.py syncdb Not Working

Tags: python, django, python-2.7, django-models, django-templates

I am trying to learn django....

I am following a tutorial and got so far as making an app ....so i opened settings.py file, and i made these changes to 'NAME' AND 'ENGINE', according to the tutorial...here:

```
DATABASES = {
'default': {
    'ENGINE': 'django.db.backends.sqlite3',
    'NAME': '~/django/bin/django_test/storage.db' 
}
```

So later in the tutorial, it says that in order to actually make such a file "storage.db" to do this:

```
python manage.py syncdb
```

this was the result:

```
/Users/angel/django/lib/python2.7/site-packages/Django-1.8.1-py2.7.egg/django/core/management/commands/syncdb.py:24: RemovedInDjango19Warning: The syncdb command will be removed in Django 1.9
  warnings.warn("The syncdb command will be removed in Django 1.9", RemovedInDjango19Warning)

Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "manage.py", line 10, in <module>
    execute_from_command_line(sys.argv)
  File "/Users/angel/django/lib/python2.7/site-packages/Django-1.8.1-py2.7.egg/django/core/management/__init__.py", line 338, in execute_from_command_line
    utility.execute()
  File "/Users/angel/django/lib/python2.7/site-packages/Django-1.8.1-py2.7.egg/django/core/management/__init__.py", line 330, in execute
    self.fetch_command(subcommand).run_from_argv(self.argv)
  File "/Users/angel/django/lib/python2.7/site-packages/Django-1.8.1-py2.7.egg/django/core/management/base.py", line 390, in run_from_argv
    self.execute(*args, **cmd_options)
  File "/Users/angel/django/lib/python2.7/site-packages/Django-1.8.1-py2.7.egg/django/core/management/base.py", line 441, in execute
    output = self.handle(*args, **options)
  File "/Users/angel/django/lib/python2.7/site-packages/Django-1.8.1-py2.7.egg/django/core/management/commands/syncdb.py", line 25, in handle
    call_command("migrate", **options)
  File "/Users/angel/django/lib/python2.7/site-packages/Django-1.8.1-py2.7.egg/django/core/management/__init__.py", line 120, in call_command
    return command.execute(*args, **defaults)
  File "/Users/angel/django/lib/python2.7/site-packages/Django-1.8.1-py2.7.egg/django/core/management/base.py", line 441, in execute
    output = self.handle(*args, **options)
  File "/Users/angel/django/lib/python2.7/site-packages/Django-1.8.1-py2.7.egg/django/core/management/commands/migrate.py", line 93, in handle
    executor = MigrationExecutor(connection, self.migration_progress_callback)
  File "/Users/angel/django/lib/python2.7/site-packages/Django-1.8.1-py2.7.egg/django/db/migrations/executor.py", line 19, in __init__
    self.loader = MigrationLoader(self.connection)
  File "/Users/angel/django/lib/python2.7/site-packages/Django-1.8.1-py2.7.egg/django/db/migrations/loader.py", line 47, in __init__
    self.build_graph()
  File "/Users/angel/django/lib/python2.7/site-packages/Django-1.8.1-py2.7.egg/django/db/migrations/loader.py", line 180, in build_graph
    self.applied_migrations = recorder.applied_migrations()
  File "/Users/angel/django/lib/python2.7/site-packages/Django-1.8.1-py2.7.egg/django/db/migrations/recorder.py", line 59, in applied_migrations
    self.ensure_schema()
  File "/Users/angel/django/lib/python2.7/site-packages/Django-1.8.1-py2.7.egg/django/db/migrations/recorder.py", line 49, in ensure_schema
    if self.Migration._meta.db_table in self.connection.introspection.table_names(self.connection.cursor()):
  File "/Users/angel/django/lib/python2.7/site-packages/Django-1.8.1-py2.7.egg/django/db/backends/base/base.py", line 162, in cursor
    cursor = self.make_debug_cursor(self._cursor())
  File "/Users/angel/django/lib/python2.7/site-packages/Django-1.8.1-py2.7.egg/django/db/backends/base/base.py", line 135, in _cursor
    self.ensure_connection()
  File "/Users/angel/django/lib/python2.7/site-packages/Django-1.8.1-py2.7.egg/django/db/backends/base/base.py", line 130, in ensure_connection
    self.connect()
  File "/Users/angel/django/lib/python2.7/site-packages/Django-1.8.1-py2.7.egg/django/db/utils.py", line 97, in __exit__
    six.reraise(dj_exc_type, dj_exc_value, traceback)
  File "/Users/angel/django/lib/python2.7/site-packages/Django-1.8.1-py2.7.egg/django/db/backends/base/base.py", line 130, in ensure_connection
    self.connect()
  File "/Users/angel/django/lib/python2.7/site-packages/Django-1.8.1-py2.7.egg/django/db/backends/base/base.py", line 119, in connect
    self.connection = self.get_new_connection(conn_params)
  File "/Users/angel/django/lib/python2.7/site-packages/Django-1.8.1-py2.7.egg/django/db/backends/sqlite3/base.py", line 204, in get_new_connection
    conn = Database.connect(**conn_params)
django.db.utils.OperationalError: unable to open database file>
```

Comment: Oo, what did you type, what should happen and what happened? Try to format your stracktrace at least and elaborate your problem a bit more in detail...

Comment: oops youre right, for some reason it didnt post properly...brb ill fix that

Answer (score 2):

The `~` sign is not expanded to you home dir so you have to manually pass the full absolute path to the database:

```
'NAME': '/home/yourname/django/bin/django_test/storage.db'
```

If `django_test` is the name of your django project then it is better to use the following code:

```
'NAME': os.path.join(BASE_DIR, 'storage.db'),
```